# Error al tomar foto con la cámara web usando la biblioteca AForge

Tags: c#, windows-forms, aforge

Estoy haciendo uso de la biblioteca de clases `AForge`.

Desde esta biblioteca, hago uso de `VideoSourcePlayer` para tomar fotos con la cámara web.

Mi propósito es crear una función que permita al usuario fotografiar imágenes para establecerlas como logotipo de la empresa. No solo puede elegir imágenes de la computadora, sino que también puede capturar imágenes desde el exterior a través de la cámara, ya que es posible que solo desee transferir un logotipo de un soporte físico (papel) al programa.

Como se ha comentado anteriormente en SO, ([how-to-pause-a-video-file-played-using-videosourceplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27738369/how-to-pause-a-video-file-played-using-videosourceplayer)), `VideoSourcePlayer` no tiene un método `Pause` ni ninguna función que permita congelar la imagen.

Sí, es cierto que tiene el método `GetCurrentFrame()`, pero que solo obtiene un `Bitmap` del fotograma actual que se debe pasar a un `PictureBox`.

Pero quiero que cuando el usuario haga clic en el botón `Capture` la imagen de `VideoSourcePlayer` simule que está congelada, y cuando el usuario presiona el botón `Delete` (sea porque no le gustó la foto), la imagen deja de congelarse y recupera su movimiento.

La lógica es como pausar o reproducir un video.

Bueno, no hay un método para eso, así que decidí buscar otra forma de obtener esto, y ...

Si se toma una fotografía, utilizo un `PictureBox` que contenga el último cuadro y que se muestre encima de `VideoSourcePlayer`, pero si se elimina, se eliminará `PictureBox` y mostrará nuevamente `VideoSourcePlayer` con vídeo otra vez en movimiento.

```
 private readonly Bitmap EmptyBitmap;

 private void CaptureBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Bitmap bitmap = this.VideoSource.GetCurrentVideoFrame();

      ShowTakedFrame(bitmap, false);
 }

 private void ShowTakedFrame(Bitmap Frame, bool remove)
 {
       var picture = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
           picture.Size = this.VideoSource.Size;
           picture.Location = this.VideoSource.Location;

           if (!remove)
           {
                this.VideoSource.Stop();
                picture.Image = Frame;
                this.Controls.Remove(VideoSource);
                this.Controls.Add(picture);
           }
           else
           {
                this.Controls.Remove(picture);
                this.Controls.Add(VideoSource);
                this.VideoSource.VideoSource = this.CaptureDevice;
                this.VideoSource.Start();
           }
 }

 private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ShowTakedFrame(EmptyBitmap, true);
 }
```

Mi problema es que al capturar la foto, la imagen capturada es de unos segundos después del momento en que presiona el botón `Capture` y cuando elimina la imagen capturada, utilizando el botón `Delete`, se quita el `PictureBox`, pero el video de `VideoSourcePlayer` se congela.

¿Puede alguien ayudarme con esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace tiempo realicé una aplicación parecida usando también la librería **Aforge**, para esto agregué:

-1 picturebox (***pbxWebcam***) donde se mostrará la imagen capturada, por defecto aparece inivisiblr y se muestra cuando realizas la captura y ahi obtienes la imagen.
-1 control VideoSourcePlayer (***servidorWebCam***) justo enfrente (de las mismas dimensiones que el picturebox) y este aparece por defecto visible.

Mi solución consiste en capturar una imagen del objeto VideoSourcePlayer de la siguiente forma:

```
      private void CreaCapturaWebcam()
      {
        Bitmap snapShotImage = servidorWebCam.GetCurrentVideoFrame();

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        snapShotImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] byteArray = ms.GetBuffer();
        pbxWebcam.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        servidorWebCam.WaitForStop();

        pbxWebcam.Visible = true;
        servidorWebCam.Visible = false;
      }
```

Y para poder cambiar o capturar una imagen, utilizo el siguiente código:

```
    private void CambiarImagenWebcam()
    {
        pbxWebcam.Image = null;
        pbxWebcam.Visible = false;
        servidorWebCam.Visible = true;
        servidorWebCam.Start();
    }
```

Si lo analizas bien, la clave está en los métodos **WaitForStop** (no uses el método Stop()) y **Start** del objeto servidorWebCam. Para validar usé el siguiente bloque en el evento clic de mi botón capturar:

```
    private void BtnWebcam_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pbxWebcam.Image != null)
        {
            CambiarImagenWebcam();
        }
        else
        {
            CreaCapturaWebcam();
        }
    }
```

Este es dependiendo si tengo una imagen previamente capturada o queremos cambiarla por una nueva captura de la webcam. Espero te ayude.